# How do I best sell my request for continuing remote work, after working remotely out of state for the past 2 years?

Tags: telecommute, remote-work

I have been working out of state, living at my parents for the past two years, and am requesting remote as we are being asked to return back to the office.  My employer has said it will be granted on a very rare basis, and I know a lot of people are interested as well.  The decision will be determined on a case by case basis.

A few facts about me:
I'm an accountant - I have specialized experience but there are always people applying for my job.
Parents are in their 60s, so not quite elderly and needing care.
They have no family nearby.
I don't want to mention this, but I have chronic issues which are controlled, and it is nice to receive care from them.
I am learning towards saying we are codependent now.
Parents can't afford to move, from their low cost of living city to my high cost of living city, especially with recent housing price increases.

So I don't really have good story.  Some people have suggested I could put down elder care, but my parents are still in their 60s.

I want to be as honest as possible in my application.  The real reason is I want to be near family now, after two years together. Leaving my job isn't possible because my job provides a pension.

How do I best sell myself for continuing remote, specifically out of state, not in commuting area?

Comment: Well your honest reason is the same as everyone elses. Perhaps tell them you'll take a pay cut?

Comment: "Leaving my job isn't possible because my job provides a pension" - I'd think there are other jobs which provide pension as well? Have you checked if there are other options that offer remote work (and pension) in your industry? Not ruling out the possibility of leaving completely might make it easier to negotiate with your current employer.

Comment: You can honestly tell your manager about your chronic medical condition and the co-dependence between you and your elder parents. That sounds like a valid reason to apply for "remote working authorization" from your company. They may or may not approve it, but at least, it does look like a valid reason for you to apply. At the same time, you can also try to apply for other "remote jobs". For example, you can go to LinkedIn and search for "Remote Accountant"

Answer (score 16):

> I want to be as honest as possible in my application. The real reason
> is I want to be near family now, after two years together. Leaving my
> job isn't possible because my job provides a pension.
>
> How do I best sell myself for continuing remote, specifically out of
> state, not in commuting area?

Your best chance comes by being honest.

Explain why remote work is best for you, and why you want to continue to live near family.

But make sure to specifically emphasize why this works out well for the company:

- you have done stellar work the past 2 years while working remotely
- you can be completely trusted to work hard independently
- you are extremely comfortable with the logistics of remote work
- you have always put in a full day's work
- your specialized experience is ideal for the role
- you are willing to attend occasional in-house company events
- whatever else makes it work out for the company

Think of it as interviewing for a job you already have.

Answer (score 10):

The major problem with your arguments so far is that they're all about you, and why it would be good for *you* personally to work remotely.

What's missing in your analysis is any thought as to the impact on your employer of you working remotely, and how you can minimise that.

- Is there something about your role which means you can work remotely more effectively than other people? If so, mention that.
- What *quid pro quos* can you offer your employer for you working remotely: you're asking them for something, what are you prepared to offer in return?
- Are there changes you can make to your role which would minimise the impact of you working remotely? If there are some bits of your role which are better done in an office, maybe you can trade responsibilities with someone who will be in the office.

If you can't offer some *substantial* reasons as to why you are a special case, honestly the most likely outcome is that your employer will want you back in the office. Whether or not that's a good policy on their part I think only time will tell.

Comment: The issue is not remote in itself, I am sure I could get local remote if I applied.  The issue is remote out of state, outside commuting area which means I cannot even go into the building if necessary unless my work pays for my trip.   I need to have reasons why I cannot move back.

Comment: @SweetTabby "I cannot even go into the building if necessary unless my work pays for my trip" Why can't you pay for the trip? I appreciate you may not _want_ to but that's a very different thing; see also [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184142/why-do-100-remote-jobs-require-employee-to-reside-in-state-x) for the additional costs you will be causing to your employer.

Comment: It is part of company rules that they have to pay for employees to come into the building and other travel expenses. They still have to factor in this cost.

Comment: @SweetTabby That's a circular argument. Offer to change the rules, that's what "case by case" means.

Answer (score -1):

From your information I cannot see anything out of the ordinary that would make you a special case.

However with the cost part it might not be that bad. With the lockdown in my country (we're small so it happened quite fast) most of the real estate bubbles have popped as people have both economised and remote worked. And they're still declining and logically I can not see them rising to their old (insane) levels again anytime in the next few years. So far they're around half the cost in the city with no takers. Landlords need tenants.

Comment: Yes, I am going to raise the cost part.